# how to approach message sending and receiving

Tags: message-queue

I have a list of messages that needs to be sent or received, depending on what the users want. received messages are needed to be verified - if it is the same with what the user is expecting.

I am thinking of looping the list, checking if the message needs to be sent. if it is a reply to a sent message, I will just wait until the message is received.

Am I in the right direction? Do I need a queue for this? I will be using grails and netty for this. I am new to both technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion if you maintain queue then that will be better and if you want to do it with more accurately then you can also use RabbitMQ like stuff. Which providing robust messaging. For details [click here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)

Comment: ok. thanks for the reply! i was wondering if i'm in the right direction. i'll check RabbitMQ. thanks again!